# How to only allow one user agent on .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, user-agent

I have been searching all over google and I really need to know how to only allow one user agent on .htaccess?

All I found is how to do it on a Dedicated or private server.

Comment: Why would you do this? If you need authentication, use the HTTP authentication means, which can be easily set up with htaccess. The User-Agent is easily spoofed

Comment: I know it can be spoofed but I would like to know.

Answer (score 11):

If the user-agent that you want to allow is: `Lynx/2.8.8dev.12`

Then you want these rules in the htaccess of the directory you want to restrict:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Lynx/2\.8\.8dev\.12 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Every other user agent is forbidden with a 403.

Comment: That was a short and very good answer. Thank you. I search that because i wanna block him from apache, not PHP because it's behind. Don't wanna tell to "someone" debug that Apache was working while php not.

Maybe the best way is blocking from firewall...but will be more suspicious. Use a custom agent is a nice trick to even secure more an API, as example.

Regards.