# Hide Cydia Repo from bring browsed on browser?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

I made a cydia repo, but I want to know how I can make the cydia repo accessible from only the cydia app... and hide the directory from being browsed/seen on an internet browser.

Example.. This is a cydia repo, full of apps, but when browsed with an internet browser, you can't see anything
http://repo.coolstar.org/

Answer (score 0):

Just put a file such as index.php into your directory. This will display a webpage when visited by a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need strong *security*, and simply want to keep the average web browser or web bot from seeing your repo, you might have to implement some kind of access control based on HTTP User Agent.

If I look at Cydia accessing my repo (in my access log), I see:

```
[22/Feb/2014:16:19:33 -0800] "HEAD /repo/Packages.bz2 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Cydia/0.9 CFNetwork/672.0.8 Darwin/14.0.0"
[22/Feb/2014:16:19:33 -0800] "HEAD /repo/Packages.gz HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Cydia/0.9 CFNetwork/672.0.8 Darwin/14.0.0"
[22/Feb/2014:16:19:34 -0800] "GET /repo/./Release.gpg HTTP/1.1" 404 13375 "-" "Telesphoreo APT-HTTP/1.0.592"
[22/Feb/2014:16:19:34 -0800] "GET /repo/./en_US.bz2 HTTP/1.1" 404 13375 "-" "Telesphoreo APT-HTTP/1.0.592"
[22/Feb/2014:16:19:34 -0800] "GET /repo/./Release HTTP/1.1" 200 215 "-" "Telesphoreo APT-HTTP/1.0.592"
[22/Feb/2014:16:19:34 -0800] "GET /repo/./Packages.bz2 HTTP/1.1" 200 3020 "-" "Telesphoreo APT-HTTP/1.0.592"
```

So, it looks like you need to allow `Cydia` and `Telesphoreo` agents.

How you do this would depend on your web server, but [here is one option if you use Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12142792/119114).  Or, [see the Apache docs here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html#env), noting their warning.

Again, this does not provide strong security.  It just hides the repo from casual browsers.